# C++ Qt program always aborts at exit with glibc detected corrupted double-linked list on SLES 11, works fine on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, qt4, suse

I have a C++ program which uses Qt 4.8. When compiled with gcc 4.6.1 on 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10 runs fine. But when compiled on 32 bit SUSE Enterprise Linux (SLES) 11 sp 1 with gcc 4.3, everytime the program exits, it crashes with

```
*** glibc detected *** /opt/myprogram: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0821dfb0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6d3d4)[0xb6fd93d4]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6d929)[0xb6fd9929]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6ec7f)[0xb6fdac7f]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb6fddcfd]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0xb71bd291]
/opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN8QMapData16continueFreeDataEi+0x59)[0xb72bdf49]
/opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4(+0xc09e3)[0xb72d39e3]
/opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4(+0xb0434)[0xb72c3434]
/opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4(+0xc17df)[0xb72d47df]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2dbe1)[0xb6f99be1]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2dc3f)[0xb6f99c3f]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0xb6f82bed]
/opt/myprogram[0x80554c1]
```

valgrind gives some not-very-helpful information about references to already freed memory blocks, but it's all stuff that happens after `main()` ends.

I'm utterly stumped about how to fix this. Does anyone have any idea what is happening or how to figure it out?

ETA: Here's the valgrind output as requested.

```
==24079== Invalid read of size 4
==24079==    at 0x7CE03B2: __tcf_0 (qatomic_i386.h:132)
==24079==    by 0x482EBE0: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EC3E: exit (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4817BEC: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==  Address 0x6a0aec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 free'd
==24079==    at 0x4028FE1: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24079==    by 0x444107C: qFree(void*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x449923F: QString::free(QString::Data*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x5F165E5: ???
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x5E2BBA3: ???
==24079==    by 0x5F4B47F: ???
==24079==    by 0x4014356: _dl_close_worker (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4014CE6: _dl_close (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549ECF3: dlclose_doit (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x400F125: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549F11B: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079== 
==24079== Invalid read of size 4
==24079==    at 0x68693E2: __tcf_0 (qatomic_i386.h:132)
==24079==    by 0x482EBE0: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EC3E: exit (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4817BEC: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==  Address 0x6a0aec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 free'd
==24079==    at 0x4028FE1: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24079==    by 0x444107C: qFree(void*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x449923F: QString::free(QString::Data*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x5F165E5: ???
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x5E2BBA3: ???
==24079==    by 0x5F4B47F: ???
==24079==    by 0x4014356: _dl_close_worker (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4014CE6: _dl_close (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549ECF3: dlclose_doit (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x400F125: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549F11B: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079== 
==24079== Invalid read of size 4
==24079==    at 0x681DB72: __tcf_0 (qatomic_i386.h:132)
==24079==    by 0x482EBE0: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EC3E: exit (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4817BEC: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==  Address 0x6a0aec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 free'd
==24079==    at 0x4028FE1: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24079==    by 0x444107C: qFree(void*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x449923F: QString::free(QString::Data*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x5F165E5: ???
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x5E2BBA3: ???
==24079==    by 0x5F4B47F: ???
==24079==    by 0x4014356: _dl_close_worker (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4014CE6: _dl_close (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549ECF3: dlclose_doit (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x400F125: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549F11B: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079== 
==24079== Invalid read of size 4
==24079==    at 0x8055F82: __tcf_0 (qatomic_i386.h:132)
==24079==    by 0x482EBE0: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EC3E: exit (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4817BEC: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==  Address 0x6a0aec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 free'd
==24079==    at 0x4028FE1: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24079==    by 0x444107C: qFree(void*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x449923F: QString::free(QString::Data*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x5F165E5: ???
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x5E2BBA3: ???
==24079==    by 0x5F4B47F: ???
==24079==    by 0x4014356: _dl_close_worker (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4014CE6: _dl_close (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549ECF3: dlclose_doit (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x400F125: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549F11B: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079== 
==24079== Invalid read of size 4
==24079==    at 0x4188F32: __tcf_0 (qatomic_i386.h:132)
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x40787C3: ??? (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libDataFileAccess.so.1.2.0)
==24079==    by 0x419802F: ??? (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libDataFileAccess.so.1.2.0)
==24079==    by 0x400FB3A: _dl_fini (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EBE0: __run_exit_handlers (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x482EC3E: exit (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4817BEC: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==  Address 0x6a0aec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 free'd
==24079==    at 0x4028FE1: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24079==    by 0x444107C: qFree(void*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x449923F: QString::free(QString::Data*) (in /opt/ncrue/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0)
==24079==    by 0x5F165E5: ???
==24079==    by 0x482EF87: __cxa_finalize (in /lib/libc-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x5E2BBA3: ???
==24079==    by 0x5F4B47F: ???
==24079==    by 0x4014356: _dl_close_worker (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x4014CE6: _dl_close (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549ECF3: dlclose_doit (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x400F125: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==24079==    by 0x549F11B: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of valgrind? (Make sure you have compiled with debugging symbols).

Comment: Yeah, compiling with debugging output is the first and most important step. As soon as you can resolve `/opt/myprogram[0x80554c1]` to a line in your source code, you should be on your way to finding a solution.

Comment: I'm going to get it rebuilt such that the link step doesn't strip the debug info (which Qt stupidly does on release builds by default).

Comment: Looks like I'm mistaken. The build scripts have already been modified to ensure debugging information is not stripped in the linking step.

Comment: Is it kept during the compiling phase (`g++ -g`)? If so, can you run it in `gdb` and see whether it gives you a line number in that case?

Comment: Yes, -g is there.

Running it under gdb, I can't get the error to happen. It exits normally, which I'm sure is because gdb is intercepting all the memory allocation/deallocation.

Comment: I had a similar problem in my own code.  Same "corrupted double-linked list" error when calling exit(0), but I didn't see the error when running with valgrind (guessing due to a race condtion?).  Turned out I was calling delete on the same object twice, once in each destructor for 2 different manager classes.

Not sure if that helps with your particular situation, but that's at least one key cause of this cryptic error.  If you haven't already, check your destructors for duplicate deletes.